# What is the memory efficient way to load 7000+ items in list view in flutter form sqlite database

Tags: android, ios, listview, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and creating an app that has more than 7000+ items preloaded into a database. I want to display all those items in a list view. I am currently querying the database once and loading all in memory and displaying it using ListView class as such.

```
ListView.separated(
 separatorBuilder: (context, int) {
  return Divider(height: 0);
 },
 controller: scrollController,
 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
 itemCount: data.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, int position) {
  Map<String, dynamic> value = data[position];
   return ListTile(title: value['value']);
 },
);
```

I find that by doing this my list view is laggy and is not performing well. Is this the right way? or may be I am doing this right but screwing some thing else?

Comment: By not specifying `itemCount`. Can you give it a try?? Any case, if you are selecting 7k+ items into memory, it is the main issue. Even if `ListView` can display efficiently you still have 7k+ items in Memory. I guess pagination is solution is here.

Comment: DON'T LOAD 7000+ ITEMS, nobody looks at that many items... Go for a pagination view and query DB on listview scroll..

Comment: Is your list view lagging in the release build as well? Keep in mind that when you run the non-release version of your app it lacks some optimizations and performance improvements. Therefore give it a try with the release compiled apk

Comment: @mdexp that was the problem. how did I miss that? thanks.

Comment: I posted that as an answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your list view lagging in the release build as well?

Keep in mind that when you run the non-release version of your app it lacks some optimizations and performance improvements. Therefore give it a try with the release compiled apk.